# Como colocar um elemento em Fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullscreen

Procurei um pouco sobre o mesmo no google e a maioria as pessoas falam para usar

```
position: absolute;
z-index:9999;
width:100%;
height:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
```

Porém o código acima só funciona para por em fullscreen dentro da janela, e não é isso que quero, eu quero usar Fullscreen de verdade, toda a tela do usuário e então achei o código abaixo:

```
if (!document.fullscreenElement &&
      !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement ) {  
    if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    }
  } else {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
      document.msExitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
      document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    }
  }
```

Esse funciona perfeitamente, porém coloca todo o documento em tela cheia, e eu quero apenas uma div especifica em fullscreen, como posso fazer isso?

Marcaram que essa pergunta é igual a essa, porém não é,  as soluções apresentadas na mesma são as mesmas que estou indagando aqui para tentar adaptar ao meu uso. [Existe alguma maneira de ativar a tela cheia do navegador com Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1855/existe-alguma-maneira-de-ativar-a-tela-cheia-do-navegador-com-javascript)

Comment: Ja tentou trocar o document pelo id da div?

Comment: Sim tentei colocando assim $(div) e obtendo a mesmo pelo getElementById mas não funcionou

Comment: Você quer o elemento em **fullscreen** (aquele que fecha o navegador todo, inclusive a barra de endereços (F11)) ou apenas sobrescrever os demais elementos do site (como o snnipet do SOpt)?

Comment: @Randrade sim eu quero colocar o elemento em fullscreen, 100% do monitor do usuário

Comment: Sua dúvida já tem resposta [nesta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1855/20615). Veja o exemplo de uma das resposta funcionando [no JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4qj5qsoL/).

Comment: @Randrade na minha pergunta eu deixei claro que esse código coloca todo o documento em fullscreen, eu quero colocar somente um elemento em fullscreen...

Comment: @LeoLetto Tens razão, falha minha. Removi o voto

Comment: @LeoLetto se ler a resposta até o fim e me disser que lá não fala nada de fullscreen eu vou acreditar, mas recomendo que leia a minha resposta especificamente por favor http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/168938/3635

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você já possui o código pronto, basta alterar o `document` para o elemento desejado, como neste exemplo abaixo:

```js
function toggleFullScreen(id) {

  var div = document.getElementById(id);

  if ((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) ||
    (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
    if (div.requestFullScreen) {
      div.requestFullScreen();
    } else if (div.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      div.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (div.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
      div.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    }
  } else {
    if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
      document.cancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
      document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="full">
  <input type="button" value="clique para alternar" onclick="toggleFullScreen('full')">

  <div class="red">
  </div>
</div>

<br/>
<div id="full2">
  <input type="button" value="clique para alternar" onclick="toggleFullScreen('full2')">

  <div class="blue">
  </div>
</div>
```

> Por motivos que desconheço, no Snnipet do SOpt o código não funciona. Mas você pode [ver o funcionamento no JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/0ontL3Lx/)

Para maiores detalhes, veja [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1855/20615).

Comment: Perfeito man, exatamente o que eu precisava.

Answer (score 0):

Esconda os outros elementos que você não quer (display: none) para apenas a tua DIV ficar a vista no full screen.

Comment: Essa é uma opção que pode funcionar, mas se houver uma forma de colocar só a div, eu acharia mais "prático"

Answer (score 0):

Segue o codigo abaixo
**HTML:**

```
<div id="DivFull">
  <canvas style="background-color:red;" />
</div>

<input type="button" value="clique para ativar tela cheia" id="btnFullScreen">
```

E em **JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$("#btnFullScreen").click(function(e){
    var el = document.getElementById("DivFull");

  // Supports most browsers and their versions.
  var requestMethod = el.requestFullScreen || el.webkitRequestFullScreen 
  || el.mozRequestFullScreen || el.msRequestFullScreen;

  if (requestMethod) {

    // Native full screen.
    requestMethod.call(el);

  } else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject !== "undefined") {

    // Older IE.
    var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");

    if (wscript !== null) {
      wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
    }
  }
});
```

SEGUE O JSFIDDLE FUNCIONANDO:

[EXEMPLO](https://jsfiddle.net/g951h7xL/)

Comment: Funcionou bem para colocar o elemento em fullscreen, mas e para voltar, através do mesmo botão? Se eu pressionar F11 ele volta ao normal, mas quero deixar a opção pra voltar ao normal por botão também

Comment: Inclua o botao dentro da div

Comment: Já tem um botão que ao ser clicado chama a função, porém não está saindo do fullscreen

Comment: No seu próprio exemplo se usar o botão para voltar, ele não funciona

Comment: Ok, estou fazendo um exemplo aqui pra resolver esse problema

Comment: Desculpe a demora, tenho demanda para fazer aqui agora. Dê uma olhada nessa biblioteca jquery ela tem a função de abrir e fechar o fullscreen https://github.com/private-face/jquery.fullscreen

Comment: Sem problemas Danilo, mas nesse caso vou usar o meu método atual mesmo e esconder os outros elementos com css, é mais prático do que adicionar uma biblioteca só pra isso